# How many possible values are there for sums of m numbers out of n numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ distinct numbers $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$; as the question title suggests, how many possible values are there for sums of m numbers out of n numbers? Or at least is there an upper bound?

Here is a simple case: consider $\{1,2\}$, so $n=2$, and assume $m=3$. Then the possible combinations are:

1. 1+1+1=3;
2. 1+1+2=4;
3. 1+2+1=4;
4. 1+2+2=5;
5. 2+1+1=4;
6. 2+1+2=5;
7. 2+2+1=5;
8. 2+2+2=6.

So there are $\textbf{four}$ possible 3-sums $(3,4,5,6)$ out of 2 numbers. But if $m$ and $n$ are larger, enumeration by brute force apparently won't work. Of course, the trivial upper bound is $n^m$, but it's not quite useful for my purpose...

Thanks and I appreciate any insights!

Comment: You can get the answer in time $\mathcal O(n ( s- nm) )$ where $s$ is the sum of all of them and $m$ is the smallest element.

Comment: Ummm... it depends on their values, don't you think?

Comment: upper bound is $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$ or $\binom{n}{m}$ depends on whether you allow to take numbers more than once.

Comment: A tighter upper bound than $n^m$ is $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$, because the order of the summands does not matter. [Function from $N$ to $X$, up to a permutation of $N$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#case_fn).

Comment: For some sets, the upper bound $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$ is optimal, for example in the set $\{1, K, K^2, \ldots, K^{n-1}\}$ where $K > m$.

Comment: Thank you guys for comments. I should add that the largest a_i is 1, and the smallest number is 0.

Comment: are they like generated randomly with some continuous distribution ? if they are then the bound is reached with probability $1$

Comment: @Robert your simple case does not satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the upper bound is $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$.  That upper bound is achieved if $a_k = (m+1)^k$ for $k= 1, \ldots, n$, so you won't be able to improve on it without imposing conditions on $a_k$.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I should add that the largest a_i is 1, and the smallest number is 0.

Comment: Are you saying the numbers are all between $0$ and $1$?  If they're linearly independent over the rationals (which will occur with probability $1$ in many distributions), then again the maximum will be attained.

Comment: That condition doesn't change the upper bound, to see this scale each of the $a_k$ in this answer by $1/(m+1)^n$ so that they now lie in the interval $[0,1]$, there will still be the same number of distinct values of the sums.